# Division of Mishnayos in Pirkei Avos / Meseches Avos

Tags: shabbat, prayer-book, mishna, pirke-avot-ethicsof

In the Siddur, Pirkei Avos has a different division (in each Perek the amount of Mishnayos) than in the Mishnayos Avos. Who determined the division of the Mishnayos in the Siddur?

Comment: There are more than two divisions of _mishnayos_ in general (not limited only to _Avos_) and they are not necessarily divided along the sidur/independent sefer line. For example, the Ramba"m's division is famously different from the standard one, which is very often different from the divisions in the Vilna sha"s.

Comment: However the Siddur is different than both of those. Who determined the division that is printed in the Siddur?

Comment: Which _sidur_ ?

Comment: All the Sedurim I have seen. Tefilas Kol Pe, Artscroll, Tikun Meir, etc.

Comment: Which difference in division are you asking about? The last two _mishnayot_ of the fifth _perek_ are probably not part of the original _mishna_, and don't appear in many manuscripts. The sixth _perek_ of _pirkei avos_ of course is not _mishna_ at all.

Comment: @Gershon - Apparently, you could make your question a lot more answerable by detailing the differences between the divisions you're asking about.

Comment: There's a footnote in Likkutei Sichos that says that the Shaar HaKollel writes that perhaps the reason that the Alter Rebbe included Pirkei Avos in his siddur was to preserve the alternate version. I'll have to find the reference, perhaps he discusses who authored which versions.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that there is no canonical division of mishnayos beyond the level of perek.

My basis for the statement is the way the Gemara handles and speaks of the mishnayos. In the Gemara, the division of the mishnayos is based only on the discussion. At times (ex. the third chapter of Taanis, starting on [18b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=10&daf=18b&format=pdf)) the Gemara will have the entire perek of mishnayos as one undifferentiated lump at the begging of the perek, followed by the Gemara. The term 'מתניתין' - "our Mishnah" - is always used to refer to the entire perek, including teachings that are found later.

Comment: Can you provide a source for this assertion? If so, please [edit] it into your answer.

Comment: I don't know of any source that says this explicitly. My basis for the statement is the way the Gemara handles and speaks of the mishnayos. In the Gemara, the division of the mishnayos is based only on the discussion. At times the Gemara will have the entire perek of mishnayos as one undifferentiated lump at the begging of the perek, followed by the Gemara. The term 'מתניתין' - "our Mishnah" - is always used to refer to the entire perek, including teachings that are found later.

Comment: I have found that there are always different ways of dividing the text of a chapter of mishnah. Between the printed Mishnaios, the printed Gemara, Rashi, Tosafos, the Yerushalmi, Rif, Rambam and Meiri, I have always found differences.

Comment: It is a reasonable guess, but the Rambam in his introduction to Mishnayos clearly says the perakim were split up into individual halachos. https://www.sefaria.org/Rambam_Introduction_to_the_Mishnah.15.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he