# Difference between Sefaria and Artscroll in enumerating Pirkei Avos

Tags: mishna, mesorah-tradition, pirke-avot-ethicsof, artscroll

There seems to be a difference in the splitting of a Perek in Pirkei Avos. On sefaria the perek I am referring to is [Perek 3](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.3.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) where the Perek in Sefaria groups certain Mishnayos in that Perek together unlike Artscroll which instead of being 18 Mishnayos, it is 23. One Mishna for example in the Artscroll is 3:19 whilst on Sefaria it is 3:15.

Is there any reason for the split and difference between these two versions?

Comment: Artscroll mishnah or Artscroll prayer book? Prayer books usually have a different division

Comment: well I know the green Artscroll Pirkei Avos Treasury it is the same as the Artscroll Prayer Book.

Comment: @ba even if it is a different division why is that the case

Comment: There are some variations on how Mishnayot are split up. Even in the Gemara some Mishnayot are split differently

Comment: Sefaria isn't a single literary standard. You can switch between multiple translations in their settings menu. So when you ask for differences between Sefaria and Artscroll, you're not speaking to a single translation. 

They currently offer 6 different options in translation (4 English and 2 Hebrew)

Comment: Besides the fact that prayer books can have a different division than _mishna_ books, there are also differences within each of those two groups.

Comment: The reason why I ask it, because I was reading a book and it brought the 3:15 variation. So they is a different split any reasons why that is?

Comment: Related: - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7692/division-of-mishnayos-in-pirkei-avos-meseches-avos

Comment: I just found out that in one manuscript, that perek has 19 mishnayos. https://manuscripts.sefaria.org/kaufman_a_50/ms50-171v-large.jpg